# Automated Release Builds using TFS and MSBuild without debug files and Web.config transforms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tfs

I have set up continuous integration for an ASP .NET MVC application on Team Foundation Server and it is building to the correct folders on a build server.

The issue I am having is that I can't get a proper release build.  I have modified the build definition so that under Process it says `Configurations to Build - Any CPU|Release` but it still includes the .pdb files with each .dll, plus it includes both Web.Release.config and Web.Debug.config.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:  Here is the file list with the config transformation files in it.  This folder is inside a folder called _PublishedWebsites, which in turn is in the Drop folder.

[image: Filelist]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project properties, on the "Build" tab, click the "Advanced" button and specify "none" for Debug info.

The Web.*.config files are copied to the drop folder because, by default they are set with a Build Action of "Content". If you don't want them, change that to "None".

Comment: Why would I want to include a Web.config file for a configuration that is not Release (i.e. Web.Debug.config)?

Comment: Web.Debug.config is not the config file for the Debug configuration. Open it up and see.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Web.config transform file.  When the build is done, as far as I understand those transformations should be applied to the Web.config file and the transform file not outputted to the build folder.  Also, if I am building a release, the transformations in Web.Debug.config shouldn't be applied anyway.

Comment: You're seeing source files. Your .cs files are there as well, aren't they? They shouldn't be in the drop folder, but they should be in the build folder.

Comment: Nope, the transform files are in the drop folder.  There are no controller or model source files, only views as per a normal MVC build.  However in the build result root folder there are both the debug and release config transform files. Updated question with a pic of the filelist.